# Could not able to connect to config server when run as cf run-task in pcf

Tags: spring-cloud, cloud-foundry, configserver

Application runs fine in normal mode.  But when run it as task using cf run task "cf run-task  ".java-buildpack/open_jdk_jre/bin/java org.springframework.boot.loader.JarLauncher" --name task1". It fails giving

```
c.c.c.ConfigServicePropertySourceLocator : Could not locate PropertySource: Error requesting access token.
```

Basically could not able to read profile SPRING_PROFILES_ACTIVE value

Comment: I'm not sure I agree with your conclusion regarding the active profiles, but honestly there is not nearly enough info here for me to say. Could you post the full output of your task running?

Answer (score 0):

I think it was not able to connect to the pcf server and get the access token, which is required to connect to the config server. This problem may arise when the application is running in a network behind a firewall and has no direct connection to internet or the pcf server.